# setTimeout parsing issue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am having an issue parsing a JavaScript setTimeout

```
setTimeout(run_function("doFirstTest", + i, "Cycle test"), delay);
```

delay and i are both variables that get instantiated locally, I can only 
think I need to some how escape the processing of the flags for the run_function
to solve my issue

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post `run_function`. Does it return a string or another function?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here is passing the return value of `run_function("doFirstTest", + i, "Cycle test")` into `setTimeout`

What you need to do is pass a function reference

```
setTimeout(function () { run_function("doFirstTest", + i, "Cycle test") }, delay);
```

Update: Furthermore, as stated in the comment below, you'll find yourself with scope issues if `i` is incremented in a loop before the timeout has executed.

If that is the case, you can create a closure which ensures `i` retains the same value which was set when the timeout was set.

```
(function (currentCount) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        run_function("doFirstTest", +currentCount, "Cycle test");
    }, delay);
})(i);
```

Comment: And, if `i` is a loop variable, there may be another problem there since `i` is used later after the `for` loop has finished.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right, I've just now added in handling for this case

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() require a function, you can try this way:

```
setTimeout(function () { run_function("doFirstTest", + i, "Cycle test") }, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code actually calls the run_function and takes it's return as a handle, to the function to be delayed. you probably want run_function itself to be delayed:

```
setTimeout(function() { run_function("doFirstTest", i, "Cycle test"); }, delay);
```